# Pass a value from one controller to another in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've been new to ASP.NET MVC. This is what I'm doing. I've 2 Controllers:Home and Customerservice. 
 Now I have a Customer list where when I click details gets redirected to the products he acquired.
So, I need to pass in the id so that the products of that customer can be displayed. So, my home consists of customer details. Now i need to pass that id to CustomerService controller ,Index action. This is what I've done in Home:

```
  public ActionResult Customers()
    {
        var dc = new ServicesDataContext();
        var query = (from m in dc.Customers
                     select m);


        return View(query);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var datacontext = new ServicesDataContext();
        var serviceToUpdate = datacontext.Customers.First(m => m.CustomerId == id);


        ViewData.Model = serviceToUpdate;
       // return View();
        return Redirect("/CustomerService");

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(FormCollection form)
    {
        var id = Int32.Parse(form["CustomerID"]);
        var datacontext = new ServicesDataContext();
        var service = datacontext.Customers.First(m => m.CustomerId == id);
        return Redirect("Customers");

    }
}
```

Now I'm not sure whether I need to pass an id as parameter for index in CustomerService. SO can you please guide me in finishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing it as a parameter is probably your best option. Try using something like `return RedirectToAction(ActionName, ControllerName, RouteValues);`.

Comment: I have one more doubt : route values is nothing but the parameter right?

Comment: If that's all you need, then yeah. So `return RedirectToAction(ActionName, ControllerName, new{id=id});`

Comment: I'm getting url?Length=11. I don't know what is that length

Comment: I'm not getting as per customers .... Do i need to change index method of Customerservice controller?

Comment: I have no idea. It's kinda hard to comment on code I can't see, given you only provided the home controller, and haven't shown your updated code either.

Comment: This syntax doesnt work. `RedirectToAction(ActionName, ControllerName, RouteValues);.`
here RouteValues = actual route values, not parameter values. But `return RedirectToAction(ActionName, ControllerName, new{id=id});` will work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using any `Redirect` (such as `RedirectToAction`) you can use `TempData` to store any parameters. The semantics have slightly changed in MVC 3 but `TempData` is designed to pass data between actions in a POST-Redirect-GET scenario.